# HTML get request with a get in action URL

Tags: php, html, get

So basically my router looks like:

```
/index.php?page=/my/page.php
```

I CAN'T change that at all.

I have a form that must be a get request... Is there an easy way to do something like:

```
<form id="frmTaxTypeReport" method="get" action="/index.php?page=/my/page.php">
```

Everytime I try, I lose the `page=/my/page.php`

If I use hidden, I get:

```
page=%2Findex.php%3Fmm%3D0%26page%3D%2Freports%2FtaxReport.php
```

Seems to escape it.

Comment: Have you tried setting your action to only `index.php` and putting `/my/page.php` as a hidden form of named element `page` ?  That will URL ecode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why so?

Put that into a hidden field

```
<form id="frmTaxTypeReport" method="get" action="/index.php">
    <input name="page" type="hidden" value="/my/page.php"/>
    ... other fields ... 
</form>
```

And it will be posted along with Form

Access that variable with `$_GET['page']`

Comment: Is there a way to NOT encode is so it looks a little nicer?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `GET` request. A `GET` request uses URL parameters to pass the data. These parameters will be intermingling or overwriting the page parameter you are passing. To get around this you can either use a `POST` or pass the page parameter as a value in the form, however I would recommend the former.

That said, if you use a hidden field, there will be no noticeable difference to the server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="/my/page.php"/>
```